# how set asp.net 5 exceptions to be like previous projects

Tags: asp.net-core

In all my experience with Visual Studio if you debug and start debugging and an exception is thrown the IDE shows you the exception and where it was thrown from.  Using Asp.Net 5 the exception is thrown but not displayed to me.  I've gone into the debug settings but it's not clear to me what I need to do to get the behavior I expect.  I don't want it returned in a page on the browser, I want to see it in the IDE.

thanks for any assistance.

Comment: This isn't different to any other version of ASP.NET. How did you enable it before? It hasn't changed AFAIK.

Comment: I didn't enable it before, it didn't need to be enabled.  What I see now is that the server had an error because I get a 500 back in the request.  When I attach a debugger the IDE does not stop on the exception and I'm not sure why.